# Read all XML files under multiple directories using python

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, lxml, elementtree

I am using Pandas through Jupyter Notebooks. I have 10 XML files which are stored in multiple locations. 
For example:

```
./A/1.xml
./A/2.xml
./A/3.xml
./B/4.xml
./B/5.xml
./B/6.xml
```

How can I load all of these files so that I can extract three particular elements in each file such as id, name and hypothesis?

I need help in the loading aspect of the question. FYI the path used above works if I do the following for each file:

```
from lxml import etree
ltree = etree.parse("./100/A/1.xml")
```

I would prefer a solution using BeautifulSoup however lxml or ElementTree is fine too.

The structure of the XML document is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pub-ref>
<doc-id>
<country>US</country>
<doc-num>05040672</doc-num>
<date>20090219</date>
</doc-id>
</pub-ref>
<app-ref>
<doc-id>
<country>US</country>
<doc-num>111324</doc-num>
<date>20100919</date>
</doc-id>
</app-ref>
```

Comment: For a one time script, I would use `subprocess.check_output(['ls', './*/*.xml']).split()` to get a list of file names.

Comment: Please post structure of XML files as it is necessary for parsing the specific values. And pandas does not have a readily available import XML function. So you have to do some data manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `glob` to get a list of all the files that match your pattern:

```
import glob
import os
from lxml import etree

dir = '/path/to/the/parent/directory/'
for file in glob.iglob(os.path.join(dir, '*/*.xml')):
   with open(file) as f:
      data = etree.parse(f)
```

Comment: can you please show me how I can extract an attribute out of that? OR is there a way to check the length of the variable data?

Comment: There are no attributes in your sample XML file, so not sure what you are asking about.

Comment: Apologies. I am very very new to this. I would like to extract the number 05040672 from this in all XML files "<doc-num>05040672</doc-num>"

Comment: so any number that is in between <doc-num> </doc-num>

Comment: The document you have posted is not well formed, are you sure that's the complete file?

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out. it was this: 
patent_id = []
for elem in data.iter(tag = 'doc-number'):
        patent_id.append(elem.text)
print(patent_id)

Comment: is there a way to extract the name of the folder from your code? or is there a way in general

Comment: `os.path.split(os.path.dirname(f))[-1]`